# How to limit parameter less template method to types of the own template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, enable-if

I have a template class that represents a special integer type.

A minimal implementation of this class could look like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Int {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>, "Requires integral type.");
    using NT = T;
    T v;
    explicit constexpr Int(T v) noexcept : v{v} {}
    
    template<typename U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<U>, bool> = true>
    constexpr auto cast() const noexcept -> Int<U> {
        return Int<U>{static_cast<U>(v)};
    }
    
    template<typename U, typename U::NT = 0>
    constexpr auto cast() const noexcept -> Int<typename U::NT> {
        return Int<typename U::NT>{static_cast<typename U::NT>(v)};
    }
};
```

There are a number of predefined type names for most common use-cases of the class:

```cpp
using Int8 = Int<int8_t>;
using Int16 = Int<int16_t>;
using Int32 = Int<int32_t>;
using Int64 = Int<int64_t>;
```

The goal is to use the types of this class naturally, yet with a set of methods. One of these methods is a `.cast<>()` method to convert between the underlying integer types:

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    auto a = Int32{10};
    auto b = a.cast<int64_t>();
    auto c = a.cast<Int64>();
}
```

To cover a wide range of uses, by the user and programatically in templates, the cast template argument shall allow the native type *and* also the template class as argument. Specifying `int64_t`, `Int64` or therefore `Int<int64_t>` shall lead to the exact same result.

**I would like to limit the second `cast` method to values of the `Int` template class.**

The approach shown in the example, will work with any class that has a type definition called `NT` in its namespace. As in my library `NT` is commonly used in template classes, it does not limit the usage of the `cast` method enough for my liking.

The following example illustrates a case I would like to avoid:

```cpp
struct Unrelated {
    using NT = int32_t;
};


int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    auto a = Int32{10};
    auto b = a.cast<Unrelated>(); // NO! is confusing, shouldn't work.
}
```

**Is there a commonly used approach to "enable" a method only with template instances of the own class?**

- I am aware there are simple solutions in C++2x. Yet, I need a solution that is working with C++17.
- The first cast method, accepting all integral types shall stay intact.

Comment: So, should you be able to cast to any standard integral type and to any `Int<integral type>` ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, casting should always result in `Int<integral type>`. I am searching for a better solution to allow `cast<[integral type]>()` *and* `cast<Int<[integral type]>>()` as the resulting syntax is easier to read.

Comment: What I meant was, should you be able to say both `cast<int8_t>` and `cast<Int<int8_t>>`? (both resulting in an `Int<int8_t>`)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, indeed, this what I am aiming for.

Comment: Ok, would you consider a solution that removes the `cast` member function and makes it a free `Int_cast` function template instead? It would be more like the other casts in the library.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, this is not the syntax I am looking into.

Comment: Something along [these lines](https://godbolt.org/z/ccMWWhbMM), perhaps.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That looks like what I had in mind - only even simpler :-) Put it up and you'll have my vote. Edit: [Possible simplification](https://godbolt.org/z/b836GY161)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, indeed! I didn't thought about this. 

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'll put up an answer using your trait. If you decide to post your own answer, I'll take mine down.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik @TedLyngmo Thank you! Also great simplification, I implemented it like this. Only thing you missed in your solution is to include the second template class parameter from the `std::enable_if`. So it needs to be `template<class T> struct IsInt<Int<T, std::is_integral_v<T>>> : std::true_type {};`.

Comment: @Flovdis Hmm, I don't get that. Why is that needed? We both removed the SFINAE from the class and replaced it with a `static_assert`. Much cleaner error messages.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Indeed, no worries, it would just be needed to match my example class. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a type trait from Igor Tandetnik (my own was uglier):

```cpp
template<typename T> struct Int; // forward declaration

template <typename T> struct is_Int : std::false_type {};
template <typename T> struct is_Int<Int<T>> : std::true_type {};
template <typename T> inline constexpr bool is_Int_v = is_Int<T>::value;
```

Then you could define the class and its `cast` like so:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Int {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>); // no SFINAE needed so use static_assert

    using NT = T;
    T v;
    explicit constexpr Int(T v) noexcept : v{v} {}
    
    template<class U> // accept all, no SFINAE needed
    constexpr auto cast() const noexcept {
        // use static_assert instead
        static_assert(std::is_integral_v<U> || is_Int_v<U>); // using the trait

        // ...and constexpr-if:
        if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<U>) return Int<U>{static_cast<U>(v)};
        else return U{static_cast<typename U::NT>(v)};
    }
};
```